# Scale a recipe in krecipes

Tags: recipe

How can I scale recipes in [krecipes](http://krecipes.sourceforge.net/)?

Suppose I have a recipe in krecipes which is for 4 persons. Now want to scale the amount of incredients that it fits for 3 persons (or even 3.5 if you have 3 adults and one child for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On their handbook page under [Recipe Actions](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/extragear-utils/krecipes/enter-edit-recipes.html#recipe-actions) you have two options, scale by yield or scale by factor. It sounds like you want the second one. Look for the <kbd>Resize recipe</kbd> button in the edit recipe page. Note that this will change the entire recipe each time you do this. Keep a backup copy of the original in case the scaling back and forth doesn't work out over time.

To request this as a feature, select `Help/Report Bug` in the menu. Type in your feature request. The KDE help document explaining this in greater detail is [here](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/extragear-utils/krecipes/report-problems.html#bugs-requests).

To do this now, you need to use one of the many online [recipe scaling calculators](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=recipe%20scaling%20calculator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gl=uk) found through a search. You probably did this already, I'm just including all the options here.

Comment: So there is no other way to do this except of editing the recipe?

Comment: It appears so. I'll update my answer with how to do a Krecipes feature request, and some other online tools for doing this now. Your question is good, you should do the feature request.

Comment: Thanks, i reported the feature request: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=292099

Comment: The feature request I reported is still unconfirmed. Is it common that this last so long or is something wrong with my bug-report?